# Laravel password encryption

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpass

I'm bringing a web application from PHP core to Laravel 4. In the current application passwords are encrypted with phpass.
Encrypted passwords of phpass are compatible with the encryption of laravel? or I have to implement phpass on laravel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to replace the default hasher, which uses the Bcrypt hashing algorithm.

Here's an example repository which shows how to do it - in his case he's replaced it with a simple MD5, but you can modify it to use whatever algorithm you like.

https://github.com/robclancy/laravel4-hashing

Answer (score 0):

There is bundle to override bcrypt hashing 
https://github.com/ksungcaya/phpass